# Unable to create TransportClient in Elastic-Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have been trying to create a TrasportClient in Elastic-Search but somehow not able to run it.

Java code:

```
package es_example.custom;

import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder;


import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class EsRoutingTransportClient
{
    // Both the IP addresses are replaced with valid IP addresses in code
    String ZEN_DISCOVERY_UNICAST_HOSTS_NO_JSON = "10.100.100.100,10.111.111.111";

    String ES_PATH_HOME = "/app/devuser/elasticsearch/dummy-path-home/";

    String ES_CLUSTER_NAME = "my-cluster"; // Verified cluster exists

    Integer ES_PORT = 9200;

    private Client client;

    public EsRoutingTransportClient()
    {
        String elasticSearchHost = ZEN_DISCOVERY_UNICAST_HOSTS_NO_JSON;
        Integer defaultPort = ES_PORT;
        String elasticSearchCluster = ES_CLUSTER_NAME;

        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("http.enabled", true)
                .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false)
                // Both the IP addresses are replaced with valid IP addresses in code
                .put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", "[\"10.100.100.100\",\"10.111.111.111\"]")
                .put("discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes", 1)
                .put("path.home", ES_PATH_HOME)
                .build();
        client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();
        parseAndAddHostPort(elasticSearchHost, defaultPort);
    }

    private void parseAndAddHostPort(String elasticSearchHost, Integer defaultPort)
    {
        String [] esHosts = elasticSearchHost.split(",");
        for (String esHost: esHosts)
        {
            String [] hostPort = esHost.split(":");
            Integer esPort = defaultPort;

            if (hostPort.length == 2)
            {
                esHost = hostPort[0];
                esPort = Integer.parseInt(hostPort[1]);
            }
            try
            {
                client = ((TransportClient)client).addTransportAddress(
                        new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(esHost), esPort));
                System.out.println("Added " + esHost + " with port " + esPort + " as a transport address");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage (String msg, String indexName, String type, String id, String routing)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] byteBuffer = msg.getBytes();
            IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex(indexName, type, id)
                    .setSource(byteBuffer)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        EsRoutingTransportClient esClient = new EsRoutingTransportClient();
        esClient.sendMessage("Hello", "storm", "json-trips", null, null);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>es_example</groupId>
  <artifactId>es-proj</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>es-proj</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <configuration />
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exlcude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:*</exlcude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>es_example.custom.EsRoutingTransportClient</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I run it as follows:

```
mvn clean package
java -jar target/es-proj-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
Mar 07, 2016 4:17:43 PM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService <init>
INFO: [Bullseye] modules [], plugins [], sites []
Mar 07, 2016 4:17:48 PM org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler doSample
INFO: [Bullseye] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{10.100.100.100}{10.100.100.100:9200}, disconnecting...
ReceiveTimeoutTransportException[[][10.100.100.100:9200][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [0] timed out after [5003ms]]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:645)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Added 10.100.100.100 with port 9200 as a transport address
Mar 07, 2016 4:17:53 PM org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler doSample
INFO: [Bullseye] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{10.100.100.100}{10.100.100.100:9200}, disconnecting...
ReceiveTimeoutTransportException[[][10.100.100.100:9200][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [1] timed out after [5002ms]]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:645)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 07, 2016 4:17:58 PM org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler doSample
INFO: [Bullseye] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{10.100.100.100}{10.100.100.100:9200}, disconnecting...
ReceiveTimeoutTransportException[[][10.100.100.100:9200][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [2] timed out after [5000ms]]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:645)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 07, 2016 4:18:03 PM org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler doSample
INFO: [Bullseye] failed to get node info for {#transport#-2}{10.111.111.111}{10.111.111.111:9200}, disconnecting...
ReceiveTimeoutTransportException[[][10.111.111.111:9200][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [3] timed out after [5001ms]]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:645)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Added 10.111.111.111 with port 9200 as a transport address
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{10.100.100.100}{10.100.100.100:9200}, {#transport#-2}{10.111.111.111}{10.111.111.111:9200}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:351)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
    at es_example.custom.EsRoutingTransportClient.sendMessage(EsRoutingTransportClient.java:82)
    at es_example.custom.EsRoutingTransportClient.main(EsRoutingTransportClient.java:94)
```

Ping to both the hosts is working from the same terminal.

(I have used 10.100.100.100 and 10.111.111.111 in the above example. In actually code-base, they are real valid IP addresses)

Also one of the nodes mentioned in the list above is master and the other one is a data node.

I am not sure how to fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The settings you're creating for the `TransportClient` are not correct. They all should be settings in the `elasticsearch.yml` file on your ES nodes. Those are settings to configure the ES server, not the ES TransportClient.

So the following settings need to be set in the `elasticsearch.yml` file on the nodes running on 10.100.100.100 and 10.111.111.111

```
cluster.name: my-cluster
http.enabled: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.100.100.100","10.111.111.111"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
path.home: /path/to/es/home
```

Also you'll need to set on each host the following setting with their proper IP address (that's the IP address each host will bind to so that other nodes and clients can see them and connect to them):

```
network.host: 10.100.100.100
```

Then you can build your ES client simply like this:

```
    Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().build();
    client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();
    parseAndAddHostPort(elasticSearchHost, defaultPort);
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you Val. I tried the above settings but it still does not work and the exception is still the same. Any more pointers? I tried port 9300 as well as 9200

Comment: Are you sure that your host list was `"10.100.100.100:9300,10.111.111.111:9300"` since 9200 is only for the HTTP interface, the TransportClient must use port 9300.